# I want to repeat video automatically with better_palyer package in flutter

Tags: android, visual-studio, flutter, mobile, video-processing

#### I tried to repeat video automatically. But it is not working.

I used better_palyer package for my flutter app.
To repeat video, I add "looping: true," into BetterPlayerConfiguration.
But it seems to doesn't work correctly.

[I don't want this button for repeating.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ttFD.png) I want to make to repeat video without pushing any button.

Comment: I set the looping value to 'true' but the app was closed with this output.

Comment: I can sympathize with *paler*.

Comment: For parts of the question I removed, please see [help on chit chat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).